# Detailed OT report - hours are doubling

Tags: sql

I am building a detailed OT report for Directors and got to the end and OT hours are doubling but not for all employees. In my query, I am using Employee 802 and the OT hours are 95 but showing as 90. I have tried everything I know.  Appreciate any help I can get!!

```
USE munprod
select 
pr_employee_master.a_location_primary [Dept Code], pr_employee_master.a_location_p_desc as Dept, 
pr_employee_master.a_employee_number [Emp Number],
CONCAT(pr_employee_master.a_name_last, ', ',pr_employee_master.a_name_first)[Employee Name],
pr_employee_master.a_job_class_desc [Job Desc], 
sum(pr_earn_history.eh_hours_worked) [OT Hours],
sum(pr_earn_history.eh_total_amount) [Total OT Amount],
max(pr_base_pay.a_salary_annual) [Annual_Salary]

from pr_employee_master, pr_earn_history, pr_base_pay
where pr_employee_master.a_employee_number = pr_earn_history.a_employee_number 
and pr_employee_master.a_employee_number = pr_base_pay.a_employee_number
and pr_earn_history.a_pay_type in ('200','201') and eh_end_date between '2018-04-01' and '2018-06-30'
and pr_employee_master.a_employee_number = '802'

group by  
pr_employee_master.a_location_primary, pr_employee_master.a_location_p_desc, 
pr_employee_master.a_employee_number, pr_employee_master.a_name_last, 
pr_employee_master.a_name_first, pr_employee_master.a_location_p_short, 
pr_employee_master.a_job_class_desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more explicit in the `WHERE` clause when you are using `CROSS JOIN` format (the commas in your `FROM` clause)

Try this, and let me know if it works. Better Solution incoming

```
FROM pr_employee_master, pr_earn_history, pr_base_pay
WHERE 
        pr_employee_master.a_employee_number = pr_earn_history.a_employee_number 
AND     pr_employee_master.a_employee_number = pr_base_pay.a_employee_number
AND     pr_earn_history.a_employee_number = pr_base_pay.a_employee_number -- Added*.
AND     pr_earn_history.a_pay_type in ('200','201') and eh_end_date between '2018-04-01' AND '2018-06-30'
AND     pr_employee_master.a_employee_number = '802'
```

A better format for your `WHERE` clause that does the same as written above.

```
FROM pr_employee_master as master  
INNER JOIN pr_earn_history  as histroy 
    ON master.a_employee_number = histroy.a_employee_number
INNER JOIN pr_base_pay as base 
    ON  base.a_employee_number = history.a_employee_number
WHERE 
    pr_earn_history.a_pay_type in ('200','201') and eh_end_date between '2018-04-01' and '2018-06-30'
AND pr_employee_master.a_employee_number = '802'
```